# Expecting: CERTIFICATE REQUEST while setting up an intermediate certificate

Tags: openssl, certificate, pki, ca

I'm trying to setup a PKI based on a CA root and  CA intermediary.

I have `scripts/generateServerCARoot.sh` which creates the CA root:

```
##!/usr/bin/env bash
set -xeuo pipefail

CA_DIR=server/generated/ca-root
REQ_DIR=server/requests

mkdir -p $CA_DIR
touch $CA_DIR/ca.index
openssl rand -hex 16 > $CA_DIR/ca.serial

mkdir "$CA_DIR/certs" "$CA_DIR/newcerts" "$CA_DIR/private"



openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -aes-256-cbc -out "$CA_DIR/private/ca.key.pem" -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096
chmod 400 "$CA_DIR/private/ca.key.pem"

openssl req -new -out "$CA_DIR/certs/ca.cert.pem" -config "$CA_DIR/ca.conf" -x509 -days 365 -key "$CA_DIR/private/ca.key.pem"

openssl x509 -in "$CA_DIR/certs/ca.cert.pem" -out "$CA_DIR/ca.pem" -outform PEM
```

With the configuration (`server/generated/ca-intermediate/ca.conf`):

```
[ req ]
default_bits = 4096
encrypt_key = yes
default_md = sha256
string_mask = utf8only
utf8 = yes
prompt = no
x509_extensions = x509_ext
distinguished_name = distinguished_name

[ x509_ext ]
basicConstraints = critical, CA:true
nameConstraints = critical, @name_constraints
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
issuerAltName = issuer:copy
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always, issuer:always

keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyCertSign, cRLSign

[ distinguished_name ]
commonName = Barracuda Root Certificate Authority

[ ca ]
default_ca = CA_default

[ CA_default ]
base_dir = server/generated/ca-intermediate
database = $base_dir/ca.index
serial = $base_dir/ca.serial
certs = $base_dir/certs
new_certs_dir = $base_dir/newcerts
default_md = sha256
default_days = 365
email_in_dn = no
copy_extensions = copy
uniqueSubject = no




policy = root_ca_policy
private_key = $base_dir/private/ca.key.pem
certificate = $base_dir/certs/ca.cert.pem

[ ca_policy ]
countryName = supplied
stateOrProvinceName = supplied
localityName = supplied
organizationName = supplied
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName = supplied
emailAddress = supplied

[ root_ca_policy ]
countryName = match
stateOrProvinceName = match
localityName = match
organizationName = match
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName = supplied
emailAddress = optional

[ intermediate_ca_policy ]
countryName = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName = optional
organizationName = optional
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName = supplied
emailAddress = optional

[ server_policy ]
countryName = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName = optional
organizationName = optional
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName = supplied
emailAddress = optional


[ name_constraints ]
permitted;DNS.0 = srv.local
```

It runs without errors.

Then I want to create and sign my CA intermediary  `scripts/generateServerCAIntermediate.sh`:

```
##!/usr/bin/env bash
set -xeuo pipefail

CA_ROOT_DIR=server/generated/ca-root
CA_DIR=server/generated/ca-intermediate
REQ_DIR=server/requests

mkdir -p $CA_DIR
touch $CA_DIR/ca.index
openssl rand -hex 16 > $CA_DIR/ca.serial

mkdir "$CA_DIR/certs" "$CA_DIR/newcerts" "$CA_DIR/private"



openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -aes-256-cbc -out "$CA_DIR/private/ca.key.pem" -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096
chmod 400 "$CA_DIR/private/ca.key.pem"

openssl req -new -out "$CA_DIR/certs/ca.csr.pem" -config "$CA_DIR/ca.conf" -x509 -days 365 -key "$CA_DIR/private/ca.key.pem"



# openssl ca -out "$CA_DIR/certs/ca.cert.pem" -config "$CA_DIR/sign-ca.conf" -extensions x509_ext -days 32 -notext -key "$CA_DIR/certs/ca.csr.pem"

# openssl x509 -req -out "$CA_DIR/certs/ca.cert.pem" -CA "$CA_DIR/sign-ca.conf" -days 32 -in "$CA_DIR/certs/ca.csr.pem"

openssl ca -batch -config "$CA_DIR/sign-ca.conf" -notext -in "$CA_DIR/certs/ca.csr.pem" -out "$CA_DIR/certs/ca.cert.pem"


openssl x509 -in "$CA_DIR/certs/ca.cert.pem" -out "$CA_DIR/ca.pem" -outform PEM

echo "Copy '$CA_DIR/ca.pem' to srv@/etc/nixos/certificates/.../ca.pem"
```

With the intermediate CA (`server/generated/ca-root/ca.conf`):

```
[ req ]
default_bits = 4096
encrypt_key = yes
default_md = sha256
string_mask = utf8only
utf8 = yes
prompt = no
x509_extensions = x509_ext
distinguished_name = distinguished_name

[ x509_ext ]
basicConstraints = critical, CA:true
nameConstraints = critical, @name_constraints
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
issuerAltName = issuer:copy
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always, issuer:always

keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyCertSign, cRLSign

[ distinguished_name ]
commonName = Barracuda Root Certificate Authority

[ ca ]
default_ca = CA_default

[ CA_default ]
base_dir = server/generated/ca-root
database = $base_dir/ca.index
serial = $base_dir/ca.serial
certs = $base_dir/certs
new_certs_dir = $base_dir/newcerts
default_md = sha256
default_days = 365
email_in_dn = no
copy_extensions = copy
uniqueSubject = no




policy = root_ca_policy
private_key = $base_dir/private/ca.key.pem
certificate = $base_dir/certs/ca.cert.pem

[ ca_policy ]
countryName = supplied
stateOrProvinceName = supplied
localityName = supplied
organizationName = supplied
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName = supplied
emailAddress = supplied

[ root_ca_policy ]
countryName = match
stateOrProvinceName = match
localityName = match
organizationName = match
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName = supplied
emailAddress = optional

[ intermediate_ca_policy ]
countryName = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName = optional
organizationName = optional
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName = supplied
emailAddress = optional

[ server_policy ]
countryName = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName = optional
organizationName = optional
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName = supplied
emailAddress = optional


[ name_constraints ]
permitted;DNS.0 = srv.local
```

And finally the configuration used to sign the intermediate CA (`server/generated/ca-intermediate/sign-ca.conf`):

```
[ req ]
default_bits = 4096
encrypt_key = yes
default_md = sha256
string_mask = utf8only
utf8 = yes
prompt = no
x509_extensions = x509_ext
distinguished_name = distinguished_name

[ x509_ext ]
basicConstraints = critical, CA:true, pathlen:0
nameConstraints = critical, @name_constraints
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
issuerAltName = issuer:copy
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always, issuer:always

keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyCertSign, cRLSign

[ distinguished_name ]
commonName = Barracuda Intermediate Certificate Authority

[ ca ]
default_ca = CA_default

[ CA_default ]
base_dir = server/generated/ca-root
database = $base_dir/ca.index
serial = $base_dir/ca.serial
certs = $base_dir/certs
new_certs_dir = $base_dir/newcerts
default_md = sha256
default_days = 32
email_in_dn = no
copy_extensions = copy
uniqueSubject = no




policy = intermediate_ca_policy
private_key = $base_dir/private/ca.key.pem
certificate = $base_dir/certs/ca.cert.pem

[ ca_policy ]
countryName = supplied
stateOrProvinceName = supplied
localityName = supplied
organizationName = supplied
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName = supplied
emailAddress = supplied

[ root_ca_policy ]
countryName = match
stateOrProvinceName = match
localityName = match
organizationName = match
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName = supplied
emailAddress = optional

[ intermediate_ca_policy ]
countryName = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName = optional
organizationName = optional
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName = supplied
emailAddress = optional

[ server_policy ]
countryName = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName = optional
organizationName = optional
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName = supplied
emailAddress = optional


[ name_constraints ]
permitted;DNS.0 = srv.local
```

However, it fails on signing the intermediate CA:

```
+ openssl ca -batch -config server/generated/ca-intermediate/sign-ca.conf -notext -in server/generated/ca-intermediate/certs/ca.csr.pem -out server/generated/ca-intermediate/certs/ca.cert.pem
Using configuration from server/generated/ca-intermediate/sign-ca.conf
Enter pass phrase for server/generated/ca-root/private/ca.key.pem:
Error reading certificate request in server/generated/ca-intermediate/certs/ca.csr.pem
140263254656832:error:09FFF06C:PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:no start line:/build/libressl-3.7.3/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:694:Expecting: CERTIFICATE REQUEST
```

I don't know why `server/generated/ca-intermediate/certs/ca.csr.pem` is not a certificate, while I used `openssl req -new`.

Which step did I miss?

Comment: You used `openssl req -new ... -x509 ...` which generates a self-signed cert, NOT a CSR which is what you want. Once you remove `-x509` you should remove `-days 32` because a CSR has no time period; only a cert does that. In addition you have the subject name of the intermediate CA the same as the root CA which will make this cert unusable because reliers will _think_ it is self-signed (even if it's not). Also I'm skeptical this is programming or development (although _in_ a script) so not officially answering.